# Django problems with static files on AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, static

I have a very weird situation with my Django Website. I put all my static and media files on an Amazon S3 bucket. The media folder is for profile, blog pictures and the static folder holds, all the css, js, img, scss etc. Everything is working fine except that the website is loading properly just when I use Safari, in Chrome it doesn't load my  tags which have bootstrap classes for images and on firefox id doesn't load the  tags and the js as well. The js is rendering my charts. What could be the problem. I'll put my cod configuration for AWS S3 and a screenshot from Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

settings.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = aws_access_key_id
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = aws_secret_access_key
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = aws_storage_bucket_name
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'ecomon.storages.MediaStore'
```

storages.py which I use for DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE (media folder):

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class MediaStore(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

How it's on Safari:
[image]

How it's on Chrome:
[image]

How it's on Firefox:
[image]

In case it's needed, the media folder it's working fine, the photos are loaded successfully, and if I upload a new one it goes where it should be.

and an example of an  tag which holds an image:

```
<div class="col-auto">
   <i class="fas fa-wallet fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of the console on each browser?

Clear browsing data on all your browsers, restart your instance, and see what happens. When something like this happens it's good to establish a baseline of what is happening. It will either load on all browsers, not load on all browsers, or if it stays the same you will know for sure to start looking into Firefox and your app. Either way you will have some idea what to look for next.